# Spring is not injecting a property

Tags: java, spring

I want to inject port value from xml file but it seems not working. Here is my xml file, what am I doing wrong?.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">
    
    <bean id="serverSocket" class="some.dir.KomunikacjaSpring.ServerSocketMy">
        <property name="port" value="3111" />
        <property name="port2" value="911" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="server" class="some.dir.KomunikacjaSpring.Server">
        <constructor-arg ref="serverSocket" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I'm trying to inject port value inside my ServerSocket class.

```
public class ServerSocketMy extends ServerSocket {
    
    
    static int port = 6066;
    int port2;

    public ServerSocketMy() throws IOException {
        super(port);
        System.out.println("PORT2: "+port2);
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }
    
    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
    
    public void setPort2(int port2) {
        this.port2 = port2;
    }
    
    
}
```

When program is running everything works perfectly but port value is not changing.

Comment: _seems not working_ is not very helpful. Explain what you expect. Explain what you see. Provide a complete example/

Comment: Sorry, I've added the class that I'm trying injecting to.

Comment: _Explain what you expect. Explain what you see._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Study bean [lifecycle and dependency injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-properties-detailed) in more depth. For your example, note:

- `MySocketServer` is constructed in one phase.
- The properties are injected in another phase.
- The value of `port2` is still `0` (default value) during construction.
- You can use [constructor argument instantiation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-constructor-injection)